# Mazda 6 TS 2006 petrol rev problem

Tags: battery, gasoline, mazda-6, welding

First ever post on here and I’m not very car savvy at all so please forgive the lack of proper terminology, a bit of background first; I bought this car in October of last year and it was going okay I guess, the drivers control of the other 3 electrical windows was pretty temperamental although recently it had been working no problem and all windows went down fine when using their own control, the oil light would come on from time to time and I would fill it up and it would usually do me 2/3 months before it came on again so I figured it was using oil but no big deal as it was driving perfectly, started first time every time, no rattles, or noises etc, until the rear lower control arm broke off when going over a speed bump in early February, that was no problem I got a new part and got it fixed, apologies if this is totally irrelevant to the problem I have now I just want to be clear what has happened since I got the car, anyway, my car was for MOT earlier this month and I decided to get my mechanic to give it a look over to see if it needed anything, he said I needed a wheel bearing and that the sills were pretty badly rusted and I could risk putting it through if I wanted to but he would recommend I got a bit of welding done as it wasn’t a major problem at the minute but could become one if the MOT person was rough with it when they were inspecting it, he referred me to a guy who does welding as he didn’t himself and I dropped my car in, got it back 2 days later and here’s where the problems start, I got in the car after he dropped it round to my house and I could get a weird smell of burning plastic, at this stage I wasn’t too worried and thought I would take it for a spinand this is where the main problem starts, I was driving and when I slowed down the revs plummeted to about 1/4 of the way above 0 as if the car was about to die and then it would flicker up and down probably between 500 and 1000 as if someone was pressing on the gas (even though I wasn’t) this happened every single time I came to a stop, on 3 occasions the car conked out, on another occasion it dropped so low all the dash lights came on as if the car had died and then it shot back up again, very strange. When I put in it reverse it almost feels like it’s ‘chugging’ along, Its really ruined the car for me I have no confidence in it anymore and am now cautious every time I’m driving it and slowing down thinking will the revs fall low enough to make the car die, I never had any issues with this before I left it in to the mechanic to get the welding done, so I have a few questions, does anybody know what this could be? Is it related to the welding? I can’t help but think it’s something this mechanic has done to my car while welding as i refuse to believe it’s coincidence that this problem has started to occur the day I get my car back from him, any advice on what to do now and possible suggestions as to what the problem is would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Some formatting would help make this readable...

Comment: Solar mike, I’m not going to take advice from a man who thinks reversing with his handbrake on has damaged his car lol